# Java 8 flatMap + Optional.of doesn't compile

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-8, option-type, flatmap

I'm trying to `flatMap` `Optional`s in Java. Here is a simplified example:

```
List<String> x = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c");
List<String> result = x.stream().flatMap((val) -> val.equals("b") ? Optional.empty() : Optional.of(val)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I get this error message from the compiler:

```
Error:(10, 27) java: incompatible types: no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist so that java.util.Optional<T> conforms to java.util.stream.Stream<? extends R>
```

What's wrong? Here is an example of what I'm trying to achieve in Scala:

```
List("a", "b", "c").flatMap(x => if (x == "b") None else Some(x))
```

It returns:

```
res2: List[String] = List(a, c)
```

as expected.

How do I convert this to Java so that it compiles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to deal with `Optional` here.

The simplest straight-forward solution is to use `filter`

```
List<String> result = x.stream()
    .filter(val -> !val.equals("b"))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you insist on using `flatMap`, you should simply use `Stream` instead of `Optional`:

```
List<String> result = x.stream().flatMap(
    val -> val.equals("b")? Stream.empty(): Stream.of(val))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you have to deal with an operation that unavoidably produces an `Optional`, you will have to convert it to a `Stream` for using `Stream.flatMap`:

```
List<String> result = x.stream()
    .map(val -> val.equals("b") ? Optional.<String>empty() : Optional.of(val))
    .flatMap(o->o.map(Stream::of).orElse(Stream.empty()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 6):

`flatMap` is expected to map an element of the input `Stream` into a different `Stream`. Therefore it must return a `Stream` and not an `Optional`.

Therefore, you should do something like this :

```
List<String> x = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c");
List<Optional<String>> result = 
    x.stream()
     .flatMap((val) -> 
                  val.equals("b") ? Stream.of(Optional.empty()) : 
                                    Stream.of(Optional.of(val)))
     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Note that if your goal is simply to get rid of some of the values ("b" in your example), you don't need to use Optional at all. You can just filter the Stream :

```
List<String> result = 
    x.stream()
     .filter (val -> !val.equals("b"))
     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This way you don't need `flatMap` and your output is a `List<String>` instead of a `List<Optional<String>>`.

As Holger commented, the solution that returns a `Stream` of `Optional`s can be simplified by using `map` instead of `flatMap`, since each element is mapped into a single `Optional` :

```
List<String> x = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c");
List<Optional<String>> result = 
    x.stream()
     .map((val) -> val.equals("b") ? Optional.empty() : Optional.of(val))
     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thanks! Normally I'd filter. In this case (the real case, not the simplified toy example) I'd rather use Optionals because filtering would mean digging through a lot of crap which I'll also have to do in the map-phase.

Comment: When every element of the stream is mapped to exactly one `Optional`, there is no need to use `flatMap`. Just use `.map(val -> val.equals("b")? Optional.empty(): Optional.of(val))`

Comment: @Holger You are absolutely right. I didn't think about it. I was following the OP's decision to use a flatMap.

Comment: @Holger If I just use .map instead of .flatMap I get List<Optional<String>> instead of the desired List<String>. And there is no flatten like in scala either :( So what's the easiest way to get to List<String>? I know I can filter and then map again, but it starts to be way too verbose...

Comment: Yeah, and I said why I'd like to use Optional in my first comment. In this toy example, yes filter would be the way to go. But I had a real-world case where optional would have been better (but only in Scala it seems, Java doesn't seem to cut it)

Comment: Stream.of and Stream.empty are just what I wanted! Thanks.